# Как включить zram?

Tags: linux, swap

Смотрю `/dev`:

```
rdice779@kali:~$ ls /dev
...
zram0
```

Так... zram0 есть... Почему бы не включить его?

```
rdice779@kali:~$ sudo -i
root@kali:~# echo '8192M' > /sys/block/zram0/disksize
echo: write error: device or resource busy
root@kali:~# mount | grep zram
root@kali:~# lsof /dev/zram0
```

Но он не включается... почему? (модуль уже включён, modprobe не нужен)

Comment: Прежде чем включать: вы уверены, что вам нужен именно zram? В современных линуксах по умолчанию уже включен zswap, который вроде тоже неплохо справляется. Если вы уверены, что хотите заменить zswap на zram, то не забудьте выключить zswap перед включением zram

Comment: посмотрите в `/proc/swaps` не включен ли он у вас уже и так. И нет, ни mount ни lsof не отображают используемые swap'ы

Comment: да, он включён (согласно proc).

Comment: Пакет `zram-config` установлен?